# Offline setting an SELinux boolean

Tags: selinux

I had an issue with an `SELinux` boolean, `allow_ypbind` that is wrongly set at 0 when starting my embedded Linux distro.

I know that at runtime I may run a `setsebool` command to set it to 1.

I need to configure my `yocto` distribution correctly and I may not be able to launch the `setsebool` command on the fly on my final distribution.

Thus I need to set this `SELinux` `boolean` offline (before the first boot): is there any configuration file that I may modify to start with `allow_ypbind=1` without the need to manually launch a command at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

All SELinux booleans have a default value according to the reference policy. With security in mind, most booleans, if enabled, remove certains limits. (Exceptions exist, such as `secure_mode` for example, which is disabled by default, but by enabling enforces strict transitions to the administrative user domain.)

That said, to override the default boolean state, you would need to ship your Yocto distribution with a prebuilt SElinux policy file that has the `allow_ypbind` boolean set to `1`. I'm not familiar with Yocto, but browsing through some posts I see that SELinux in Yocto is called `meta-selinux` and added to Yocto as a layer and it is built from source (found [here](https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-selinux)).

You'd have to clone that repo, and patch the policy to your liking.

Good luck!